# php and firefox integration/mime compatibility

Tags: php, firefox

I just installed php5, apache, and mysql so I can try to get back into some web dev stuff.

In any case I'm trying to drag and drop a php file from some php script stuff(not mine but says I can just drag and drop it onto the browser to set it up) onto firefox but I get the save-as dialog.

Firefox5 is not "running" the php as expected. There is no mime type association with php and I wouldn't know how to begin to get firefox to use the php interpreter.

Any ideas how I can get firefox to "run" php files? e.g., drag and drop a php file into firefox or address bar of firefox and it uses the php5 installation to execute the php and display the results.

I haven't checked to see if apache is executing php files but I imagine it is. I simply do not want to have to copy the php file to have apache deal with it as I would like firefox to handle it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser - whether Firefox or otherwise - does not understand PHP files. PHP is a *server-side* scripting language, which means that the PHP code is executed on the web server. The PHP code can then produce HTML, Javascript, etc which is understood by the browser.

You'll need to put the PHP files into Apache's "htdocs" folder and visit http://servername/myscript.php (for example - if the web server is running on the same computer it would be http://localhost/myscript.php) to view them.

Comment: As I said, thats why firefox needs to execute php and why I SAID I did not want to have to use apache. Surely there must be some way. I have php5 installed and firefox simply needs to display the output of the php file. It shouldn't be that difficult to do. Firefox -> php5 -> firefox. I don't mind installing an extension or script to handle this if necessary.

Comment: It's not rocket science to have php interpret the php file for firefox. I can't imagine someone not having gotten this to work.

Comment: It would be a very strange environment - many PHP scripts rely on environment variables that Apache provides. PHP can call things that shouldn't be allowed through the browser (yipee, a website can call system() on your computer!) and has configuration settings that would now have to be relocated. Connecting to a database would require sending the database connection string **and enough of a password to authenticate with** to the browser.

Comment: Now, you could say, well, I just want a quick development environment. But it's dead-easy to get an Apache/PHP/MySQL environment set up using something like [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), which gives you a proper (for dev at least) environment in which everything works in the same way as it will when you come to deploy something. Now, yes, it could be done, but I'm really just not seeing the benefit.

Comment: your right about the environment but there are three ways one can go. One could actually pass the php to apache essentially just copying it to the apache folder and then redirecting to that(so file://... becomes http://localhost...) in which case you end up running in apache). One could simulate several of the environment variables and stuff to get a half working server like environment. Or all that could be ignored. PHP is not a web programming language and does not require apache. It is first and foremost a programming language. So it can still be useful to run php scripts that are not web

Comment: @AbstractDissonance - that's true. And, for example, you could run PHP using CGI, the exact same way that a web server could use an application written in any programming language it didn't have a specific interface (C or Lisp or Haskell or anything really). And you could run PHP on the command line, redirect output to a file, and open the resulting file in your browser. However, running PHP via Apache would be faster than the first and more powerful than the second.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2391/discussion-between-jivlain-and-abstractdissonance)